# Sorting columns in a SQL Server view results in different performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flzPU.png)I have a problem with sorting results in a SQL Server view, when I sort by one of the columns which is `nvarchar`, it sorts fine and quick; when I sort by another column which is from the same table as the first one and is also of type `nvarchar`, it takes 6 minutes comparing to 10 seconds on the first column, why is that?

I have multiple columns and multiple joins in that view, but it is sorting that is causing the performance problem

Comment: You simply DO NOT sort columns in a view. TOP 100 PERCENT is an illusion of "sorting" if that is your chosen technique. The query that generates a resultset is what determines the order of rows and that is done using an ORDER BY clause in that query. If this is a general performance question that involves a query using a view, then post the DDL of the tables and view involved and the actual query. To investigate performance issues you will also need (and post) the execution plan.

Comment: I understand, seems the issue with the query accessing the view, query plan looks ok the only thing it seems spending time is scanning index on one of the tables under the view like 90% of the time

Comment: it looks like: Select bunch of columns from View1 order by view1.column1 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY = RUNS PERFECT                                 
Select bunch of columns from View1 order by view1.column2 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY = RUNS FOR NUMBER OF MINUTES August 2020

Comment: Presumably, on `Column2` there isn't an index to help the instance sort the data; so it has the sort the entire data set first. Without the query, or a consumable query plan (and ideally the DDL for the table and indexes) we can't do more than guess.

Comment: We need to see the full query plan, can you share it via https://pastetheplan.com

Answer (score 0):

The target column is not in the index OR execution plan fails to utilize such index.

I agree with SMor in that you need to obtain, review (and post here) the actual execution plan.

See also [how to display execution plan is MS SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan)

Comment: not sure how can I add image here

Comment: looks like I have clustered index scan that take 6 minutes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).